# Nest.js swagger plugin not found under jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

With Nest.js i'm using @nestjs/swagger plugin. all works well on dev.
in jekins, i'm pulling the code, and doing a build. For that, i have installed nest cli on the server.
i'm getting this error at the build stage:

```
> nest build
Error  "@nestjs/swagger/plugin" plugin could not be found!
```

what am i doing wrong?
server is ubuntu 17, in my nest-cli.json i have this:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": ["@nestjs/swagger/plugin"]
  }
}
```

and again, it works fine locally. problem is only on jenkins workspace. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest plugin can be found under your node_modules directory under: @nestjs/swagger/dist/plugin

This should be set in your complier options:

```
"compilerOptions": {
     "plugins": ["@nestjs/swagger/dist/plugin"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue.

I solved it with this:

1. Make sure you have nestcli installed: `npm i -g @nestjs/cli`
2. Update nestcli on deployment before you make npm install: `nest update`
3. If this not helps, try another Swagger-Version. I had the problem with version 4.5.9, I upgraded to `@nestjs/swagger": "^4.5.11` and it helped.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the "@nestjs/swagger/plugin" plugin is not installed error.

In my case, the problem was an old node version. Render.com (where my server is hosted) uses Node version 14 as the default. As a result, the plugin-detector was not able to locate my plugin even though it was installed, along with reflect-metadata.

Nest.js, as of now, requires Node.js version 16 or higher:
https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps#prerequisites

Adding these lines to the root of my package.json forced Render.com to use a more recent version:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend anyone who is encountering this error to put a log into the cli source code at exactly [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/blob/master/lib/compiler/plugins-loader.ts#L55).

The `nest` cli hides the true error message from requiring plugins - so it could be a whole host of issues.

In my case I was missing `reflect-metadata` package after switching over to a new monrepo.

`Module 'reflect-metadata' not found`

So just make sure you have all the required modules for NestJS

Comment: yeah! it helped me, reflect-metadata was exectly what I was missing!
Thank you!